How to extend an interface but limit the keys to a specific list
In typescript, how can I extend an existing interface but limit the use to the same keys?
Existing interface:
interface First {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
}

interface Second extends First {
  key1: number;
  key3: string <<< this must be prevented and generate error!
}

The example is intentionally reduced to understand the topic, obviously the application is for much more complex interfaces.
In all the tests I've done, when I extend an interface I can always add any kind of new key.

What is the problem in this? If you are extending an interface, you want to add some more keys to it. if you don't want to add more keys, then you don't add those keys. You can't limit the keys that can go inside an interface.

This looks like XY problem. You should ask about real problem which you are trying to solve.

Seems like you rather want to re-map the keys to other/wider type, instead of extending?

I think that it's the whole point of extending an interface, it's to add more properties, not to change existing properties types.

You can't make key1 a number by interface extension even if you could prevent key3. Please [edit] to either make key1 more specific than string (e.g., "a" | "b") or to make the question not about interface extension. If you're changing string to number then your use case doesn't come close to what interface extension gives you and this is an XY problem. Please edit to clarify.

You can just override :
type Override<T, U extends { [K in keyof T]?: any }> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U[K] ? T[K] : U[K]
}

interface First {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
}

interface Second extends First {
  key1: number;
  key3: string
}

type Third = Override<First, {key1:number}>

var myOverride:Third = {
  key1: 5,
  key2: 'six'
}

